# Facebook like button notification

Tags: facebook-like

I apologize for the beginner question but I don't know where else to turn.
I have the following code in my website:

```
<script>
  FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
    alert('You just liked the page!');
  });
</script>
```

On the developer page, it states that it will record likes in the database. Well, how do I view them?

The button shows up fine and everything is working properly but I just don't know how to view them.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have posted is for notifying your page (in Javascript obviously) that the user viewing the page has 'liked' it.  This is not actually needed in order for the Like functionality to work.

You need to have the Like button on the page already for someone to Like the page (eg. by using the  tag with the necessary Javascript SDK loaded - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ - though it sounds like you already have that done).

As for viewing the 'likes', your Like button will tell you how many people have liked it (if you have that option set), however you cannot directly view who actually Liked your page as Facebook do not allow that (privacy concerns)

The script that you posted can be modify to perform other actions, for example you could make an AJAX call to your own server to record information of the 'like' - eg. if the users are logged in, then you would know who it was that liked it.

Comment: Thanks Stevie for the perfect explanation. I already have the Like button working properly but was just interested in more data about who's actually liking the page. Since I have no idea how to set up an AJAX call, the script above can be removed, correct? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, the script can be removed, it is not required if you are not performing any action yourself when the user likes the page.